# How do I check if pairs of ints exist in array X, then remove the specific values that form the pairs from array Y?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, filter

How do I check if `j, k[anything][0]` pairs exist in array `roads`, then filter out specific values that form the pairs in array `roads` from array `k`? The pairs can be flipped as `k[anything][0], j`.

For example, do `[1, 0]` and `[1, 3]` exist in `roads`? Or `[0, 1]` and `[3, 1]`.

```
const j = 1;
let k = [["0", 2],["3", 2]];
const roads = [[0,1],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3]];
```

I wrote a block, but it breaks when iterating when there are no more elements in `k` since `roads.length` is greater than `k.length`.

**What I have so far. FYI, it's broken:**

```
for(let i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
  let pairs = ([a, b]) => a === k[i][0] && b === j || a === j && b === k[i][0];
  if(roads.some(pairs)) {
    k = k.filter(x => x[0] !== k[i][0])};
};

console.log(k)
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
k = [];
```

**Second example:**

```
const j = 1;
let k = [["0", 2],["3", 2],["5", 2]];
const roads = [[0,1],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3],[5,6],[5,7]];
```

**Second desired outcome:**

```
k = [["5", 2]];
```

Comment: Why are you using `k[i]`? `i` is only the index into `roads`, it has nothing to do with `k`.

Comment: Can `k` be longer than 2?

Comment: Why isn't `[1, 2]` in the expected result? There's no `2` in `k[0][0]` or `k[1][0]`.

Comment: And `[0, 3]` should be in the result, since it doesn't have `j`.

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Do the pairs matter at all, or are just checking if any number present in `k` exists within `roads? Are you trying to find any roads that contain any of the pairs in `k`? I'd suggest adding another example that shows a desired result with an actual value instead of an empty array since there's not much to go off

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks for your questions, Barmar. I'll try to answer them here. "Why are you using k[i]?" I'm not sure how else to iterate through roads and k at the same time. "Can k be longer than 2?" k can be longer than 2. But it cannot be longer than roads.length. "Why isn't [1, 2] in the expected result?" If k[1][0] or/and k[0][0] values form pairs in array roads with j, I want to filter out k[1][0] or/and k[0][0] from array k.

Comment: You don't need to iterate through roads and k at the same time. They should be nested loops with their own indexes, not parallel loops with the same indexes, since the matches  aren't at the same indexes.

Comment: I still don't understand why `[1, 2]` isn't in the answer. `k[1][0]` is `3`, `k[0][0]` is `0`. Neither of them is in `[1, 2]`.

Comment: @Rylee - I added a second example for clarity.

Comment: @Barmar - [1, 2] should not be the answer because we are filtering out values that have pairs from array k. Array k does not include [1, 2] to begin with.

Comment: Your code ends with `k = roads.filter(i => i[0] !== k[i][0])` so I thought you want to filter from `roads`, not `k`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223371/discussion-between-peyo-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusing part of this question is that you're essentially not using the second index in `k`. You're only checking for pairs `[ j, k[anything][0] ]`

This makes `k[anything][1]` irrelevant for filtering, correct? If so, see the code below

```js
const j = 1;
let k = [["0", 2],["3", 2],["5", 2]];
const roads = [[0,1],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3],[5,6],[5,7]];

// results will return the filtered array
// you can instead change `let results` to `k`
// if you want to set it directly
let results = k.filter(kPair => {
    let roadsContainPair = roads.some(roadPair => {
            // check the two cases
            // [j, kPair[0]] and [kPair[0], j]
            return (roadPair[0] === j && roadPair[1] === parseInt(kPair[0])) ||
                (roadPair[0] === parseInt(kPair[0]) && roadPair[1] === j);
        });
    
    // since we only want the pair if roads DOESN'T contain it
    // we return the negative of roadsContainPair
    // i.e. if the current "pair" is found in roads, filter it out
    return !roadsContainPair;
});

// results = [["5", 2]];
```

Comment: Note that I'm using `parseInt`, you may also need to do this for `roadPair[anything]` if they are not stored as integers

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. To provide more context, I've been working on a leetcode problem, and this was a particular section I didn't know how to code. I successfully wrote code that solved the problem. It's likely not the most efficient way to write it but it's fast. [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximal-network-rank/discuss/903980/(Javascript)-Complex-(96-ms-faster-than-98.79-43.5-MB-less-than-5.45))

Answer (score 1):

Use `some()` to test if there are any matches for a condition in an array. Use this in your `if` condition to see if any of the pairs are in `roads`.

Use `includes()` to test if a value is in an array. Use this when filtering `k`.

```js
const j = 1;
let k = [
  ["0", 2],
  ["3", 2]
];
let roads = [
  [0, 1],
  [0, 3],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 3]
];
let k_parsed = k.map(([x]) => parseInt(x));
if (roads.some(([rx, ry]) => k_parsed.some(kx => (rx == j && ry == kx) || (rx == kx && ry == j)))) {
  k = k.filter(([kx]) => !k_parsed.includes(parseInt(kx)));
}

console.log(k);

k = [["0", 2],["3", 2],["5", 2]];
roads = [[0,1],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3],[5,6],[5,7]];

k_parsed = k.map(([x]) => parseInt(x));
if (roads.some(([rx, ry]) => k_parsed.some(kx => (rx == j && ry == kx) || (rx == kx && ry == j)))) {
  k = k.filter(([kx]) => !k_parsed.includes(parseInt(kx)));
}

console.log(k);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks like the code works for the first scenario, but not for the second.

Comment: It's just by accident in the first case. I think my code now always removes everything from `k`.

Comment: What do you think about this so far? For some reason, `roads.some(pair)` returns `false`. `for(let i = 0; i < k.length; i++) { const pairs = ([a, b]) => a === k[i][0] && b === j || a === j && b === k[i][0]; if(roads.some(pairs)) { k = k.filter(x => x[0] !== filteredResult[i][0])};};};`

Comment: It's hard to read code in comments, so I'm not sure. Edit the question and put it in a formatted code block.